# Replacing a common page in a PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a page that's repeated hundreds of times throughout a several thousand page PDF. I need to make a change to that page, and I want the change reflected throughout the document.

I've done some similar jobs with Javascript in Acrobat before, but I'm having trouble identifying the relevant pages.

How can I automatically recognise and swap out this certain page, throughout the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by using `this.getPageNumWords(page)` to work out how many words were on the common page. This number just happened to be unique, so provided an easy way to work out which pages to switch out when looping over.

For further useful methods, check out the [Javascript API reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf).